# Google Speech to Text integration with Asterisk live calls

Tags: php, asterisk

i have setup google speech to test with asterisk. i have done following to get speech to text.

when call comes in i record the message,
convert to google supported bit rate audio file using sox
send the audio file to google cloud speech and get the response.

is there anyway we can send live call audio instead of recording to google cloud speed and get response?
please see my following code.

```
<?php
        require_once('/scripts/phpagi/phpagi.php');

$agi = new AGI();
$agi->answer();

$unique_id = "$argv[1]";
$caller_id = "$argv[2]";

$agi->record_file("/scripts/google-speech-to-text/recordings/$unique_id-$caller_id","wav",' ',-1,null,false,5);


echo system("sox /scripts/google-speech-to-text/recordings/$unique_id-$caller_id.wav -b 16 -s -c 1 -r 16k -t raw /scripts/google-speech-to-text/recordings/$unique_id-$caller_id.raw");

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/scripts//file.json');

# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Speech\SpeechClient;

# Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
$projectId = 'myprojectid';

# Instantiates a client
$speech = new SpeechClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
    'languageCode' => 'en-US',
]);

# The name of the audio file to transcribe
$fileName = '/scripts/google-speech-to-text/recordings/$unique_id-$caller_id.raw';

# The audio file's encoding and sample rate
$options = [
    'encoding' => 'LINEAR16',
    'sampleRateHertz' => 16000,
    'model' => 'phone_call',
];

# Detects speech in the audio file
$results = $speech->recognize(fopen($fileName, 'r'), $options);

foreach ($results as $result) {
$getresult =  $result->alternatives()[0]['transcript'] ;

}

echo $getresult;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use EAGI to do continiuos recognition.

Unfortanly it not stable(do core dump etc) enought at current moment

Comment: does it live speech recognition or same i have to record the voice and get the result?

Comment: No,it is continious via GRPC

Comment: I followed https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize  to setup recorded file streaming and its working fine.
is there any example of live call streaming in php script?